# Ignite server is running with jmx disabled by default

Tags: ignite, jmx

When I start ignite, it shows the below logs

```
[18:45:20,178][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Remote Management [restart: on, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
```

Here, `JMX (remote: off)` indicates that JMX is disabled but I am not able to figure out why JMX is disabled on my ignite node. I have not specified `-nojmx` option anywhere. 
I am using apache ignite version 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

This message just says that Ignite remote management via JMX is disabled on particular node (meanwhile JMX may be enabled as part of JVM). Check out javadoc of `IgniteKernal#isJmxRemoteEnabled()`

```
/**
 * Whether or not remote JMX management is enabled for this node. Remote JMX management is enabled when the
 * following system property is set: <ul> <li>{@code com.sun.management.jmxremote}</li> </ul>
 *
 * @return {@code True} if remote JMX management is enabled - {@code false} otherwise.
 */
```